# how to remove lines containing only numbers, special characters or blanks after a delimiter

Tags: bash, macos

The following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

osascript -e \
'tell application "Google_Chrome" to tell tab 1 of window 1 \
set t to execute javascript "document.body.innerText" \
end tell' | grep ':'
```

Results in output:

```
line1:blah blah 
line2:blah 123 
line3: 
line4:[456] blah
Line5:blah blah
line6:[789]
line 7:
```

The desired output:

```
line1:blah blah 
line2:blah 123 
line4:[456] blah
```

I can use `cut -d : -f1` to get just the left side and `cut -d : -f2` to get just right side. But I can't seem to figure out how to remove blank lines or lines with only numbers and/or special characters while still preserving the structure of data.

To the best of my knowledge, what I'm trying to achieve follows this specific set of rules:

- Every valid line of output contains a `:` (*but not all lines containing `:` are valid*)
- No spaces, special characters or capital letters permitted to the left of `:`
- Only **lowercase letters**, **numbers** and **underscores** `[a-z]` `[0-9]` and `_` permitted to the left of `:`
- Any line **not** containing letters `[a-z]` to right of `:` should be discarded. (case is not important)

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: It's been a while since I've used `awk` but something like: `... | awk -F':' '{NF>1; print $0}'`?

Comment: `sed '/^[a-z0-9_]\{1,\}:.*[a-zA-Z].*$/!d'`

Comment: `awk` did not work but `sed` did what I needed perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Since you're already using a `grep` to get a line containing `:` you don't another `sed` or `awk`. Just replacing your `grep` with suggested `grep` expression below will be sufficient and will involve one less command in your pipeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your `grep` with this:

```
... | grep -E '^[a-z0-9_]+:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]'

line1:blah blah
line2:blah 123
line4:[456] blah
```

This will meet your requirements of allowing only `[a-z0-9_]` characters on left of `:` and at least one of `[a-zA-Z]` on RHS of `:`.

Comment: ` *` is not needed as it is included in `[^a-zA-Z]*`

Comment: Both this and the sed solution in the comments above work very well. Could you sort of explain why they work so I can try to wrap my brain around what's going on?

Comment: Yes I added some explanation in my answer as well. `[a-z0-9_]+` matches 1 or more of given characters in character class `[...]`. `:` matches literal colon and `[^a-zA-Z]*` matches 0 or more of any characters that is not one of those in character class.

Comment: How would you then also allow allow for cyrillic characters to the right of colon?

Comment: Use: `grep -E '^[a-z0-9_]+:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-ZА-Яа-яЁё]'`